# DictProperty has no attribute "requests_recycle_view". Python

Tags: python, kivy, pyrebase

I need to refresh recycle view when I recive data from stream. When I run below code I see

> AttributeError: 'kivy.properties.DictProperty' object has no attribute
>   'requests_recycle_view'

It comes from method`recycle_view_list` I think there is some issue with instances but can't solve it. When I comment `self.ids.requests_recycle_view.data = self.requests_tab` and run `refresh_recycle_view` from button it works - I mean it refresh the list on the screen but I need it to run automatically when data in `requests_tab` changes from stream.

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'multisamples', '0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import pyrebase
from kivy.properties import  ListProperty

config = {
    "apiKey": "String",
    "authDomain": "String",
    "databaseURL": "String",
    "projectId": "String",
    "storageBucket": "String",
    "messagingSenderId": "String"
  };

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
db = firebase.database()

Builder.load_file('kv/main.kv')




#-------------------------------------------------------------ScreenManager

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass




#--------------------------------------------------------------RequestScreen

class RequestScreen(Screen):

    requests_tab =  ListProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def refresh_recycle_view(self):
        print('refresh',  self.requests_tab)
        self.ids.requests_recycle_view.data = self.requests_tab


    def recycle_view_list(self, listFromStream):
        print("recycle_view_list", listFromStream)

        self.requests_tab = listFromStream
        self.ids.requests_recycle_view.data = self.requests_tab

    @classmethod
    def setRequestTab(cls, tab):
        print("setRequestTab", tab)
        cls.recycle_view_list(RequestScreen ,tab)





# ------------------------------------------------------------stream_handler
def stream_handler(message):
    print(message["event"])  # put
    print(message["path"])  # /-K7yGTTEp7O549EzTYtI
    print(message["data"])  # {'title': 'Pyrebase', "body": "etc..."}

    pyreMessage = [{'text': message["data"]}]

    RequestScreen.setRequestTab(pyreMessage)



db.child("Requests").stream(stream_handler)




#---------------------------------------------------------------StreamApp
class StreamApp(App):
    def build(self):

        sm = ScreenManagement()
        sm.add_widget(RequestScreen(name="Bajot II"))
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    StreamApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
#main.kv
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition


<ScreenManagement>:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    RequestScreen:

<CustLabel@Label>
    halign: 'right'
    valign: 'middle'
    width: 80

<RequestScreen>
    name: "RequestScreen"

    requests_tab:   requests_recycle_view.data


    Button:
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 42
        text: "Done"
           on_press:   root.refresh_recycle_view()



    BoxLayout:
        #size_hint_y: None

        RecycleView:
            id: requests_recycle_view
            viewclass: 'CustLabel'
            data: root.requests_tab
            RecycleBoxLayout:
                spacing: 15
                default_size: 100, dp(25)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to test this (I don't have your database), but I think it will work. I think your statement about instances is right. In the modified code below, I changed `setRequestTab` to an instance method:

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'multisamples', '0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import pyrebase
from kivy.properties import  ListProperty

config = {
    "apiKey": "String",
    "authDomain": "String",
    "databaseURL": "String",
    "projectId": "String",
    "storageBucket": "String",
    "messagingSenderId": "String"
  };

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
db = firebase.database()

Builder.load_file('kv/main.kv')




#-------------------------------------------------------------ScreenManager

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass




#--------------------------------------------------------------RequestScreen

class RequestScreen(Screen):

    requests_tab =  ListProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def refresh_recycle_view(self):
        print('refresh',  self.requests_tab)
        print(self.ids.requests_recycle_view)
        self.ids.requests_recycle_view.data = self.requests_tab


    def recycle_view_list(self, listFromStream):
        print("recycle_view_list", listFromStream)

        self.requests_tab = listFromStream
        self.ids.requests_recycle_view.data = self.requests_tab

    def setRequestTab(self, tab):
        print("setRequestTab", tab)
        self.recycle_view_list(tab)




# ------------------------------------------------------------stream_handler
def stream_handler(message):
    print(message["event"])  # put
    print(message["path"])  # /-K7yGTTEp7O549EzTYtI
    print(message["data"])  # {'title': 'Pyrebase', "body": "etc..."}

    pyreMessage = [{'text': message["data"]}]

    App.get_running_app().requestScreen.setRequestTab(pyreMessage)



db.child("Requests").stream(stream_handler)




#---------------------------------------------------------------StreamApp
class StreamApp(App):
    def build(self):

        sm = ScreenManagement()
        self.requestScreen = RequestScreen(name="Bajot II")
        sm.add_widget(self.requestScreen)
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    StreamApp().run()
```

I have saved a reference to the `RequestScreen` in the `StreamApp`, and then used that reference in the `stream_handler()`. That allows me to call `setRequestTab()` as an instance method. Again, this code is not tested, so there may be some errors.

Comment: Error: `App.get_running_app().requestScreen.setRequestTab(pyreMessage)
 AttributeError: 'StreamApp' object has no attribute 'requestScreen'`. If you can help I will create database for tests.

Comment: Did you make the change in the `build()` method? (`self.requestScreen = RequestScreen(name="Bajot II")` and `sm.add_widget(self.requestScreen)`)

Comment: Yes I have. That's a bit odd for me now.

Comment: Another possibility is that your `stream_handler` is getting called before the `StreamApp` is setup. If that is the case, then perhaps moving the `db.child("Requests").stream(stream_handler)` into a method of the `StreamApp` and calling that method via a `Clock.schedule_once()` in the `build()` method might fix it. You could also make `stream_handler` another method of the `StreamApp` and eliminate the need for the `App.get_running_app()` call.

Comment: Ok I will try. In the meantime I have set `Clock.schedule_interval` for `refresh_recycle_view`. I can see that clock works but the view does not refresh. I need to get a bit more knowledge about live cycle and how it accually works rather than just searching for ready solutions. Now it is a magic. Thanks for your help. I will come back later.